# I would like to hide and display two div

Tags: html, angularjs

With my application, I want to display the div2 by clicking the div1 and thus hide the div 1 and when I click on the div2 the div1 appears and div2  disappears.

I made this code but it does not work.

```html
<div ng-click="show2=true; show1=false" ng-show=show1">
  <center>
    <i class="ion-arrow-down-b flecheCacherTacheEffectuee"></i>
    <span class="titreTacheEffectue">TÂCHES EFFECTUÉES</span>
  </center>
</div>
<div ng-show="show2" ng-click="show1= true; show2=false">
  <center>
    <i class="ion-arrow-up-b flecheCacherTacheEffectuee"></i>
    <span class="titreTacheEffectue">TÂCHES EFFECTUÉES</span>
  </center>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `ng-show=show1"` looks " is missing

Comment: The `<center>` element is obsolete. Don't use that. https://developers.whatwg.org/obsolete.html#obsolete

Answer (score 0):

change ng-show=show1" to ng-show="show1".

```html
<div ng-click="show2=true; show1=false" ng-show="show1">
      <center>
        <i class="ion-arrow-down-b flecheCacherTacheEffectuee"></i>
          <span class="titreTacheEffectue">TEST 1</span>
      </center>
    </div>
    <div ng-show="show2" ng-click="show1= true; show2=false">
      <center>
        <i class="ion-arrow-up-b flecheCacherTacheEffectuee"></i>
          <span class="titreTacheEffectue">TEST 2</span>
      </center>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using js:

```js
function change(div_hide, div_show) {
  var divA = document.getElementById(div_hide);
  var divB = document.getElementById(div_show);
  divA.style.display = "none";
  divB.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" onclick="change('div1','div2');">
  <center>
    <i class="ion-arrow-down-b flecheCacherTacheEffectuee"></i>
    <span class="titreTacheEffectue">TÂCHES EFFECTUÉES DIV1</span>
  </center>
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;" onclick="change('div2','div1');">
  <center>
    <i class="ion-arrow-up-b flecheCacherTacheEffectuee"></i>
    <span class="titreTacheEffectue">TÂCHES EFFECTUÉES DIV2</span>
  </center>
</div>
```